# cursor changed outside of the current window

Tags: windows, cursor

I have read a lot of posting, they were all talking about how to change cursor permanently within the current window. However, I want to have the cursor changed outside of the window as well. I am be able to change the cursor permanently within the window, but when i move the cursor outside of the window, it changes back to normal cursor. Here is part of the code that set cursor within current window.

```
void colourpicker::OnSelectTool(wxCommandEvent & e) {
    m_enableDropper = true;
    m_timer = new wxTimer(this);

    m_parent->SetCursor(wxNullCursor);
    m_parent->SetCursor(* m_dropperCursor);
    m_timer->Start();
}

void colourpicker::OnTimer(wxTimerEvent& event) {
    if (::wxGetMouseState().LeftDown() && m_enableDropper) {

        ... //pick the color

        m_parent->SetCursor(* wxSTANDARD_CURSOR);
        m_timer->Stop();
    }
```

}

Comment: The cursor is strictly set by the window underneath it. If it's moved outside your window, you lose control over setting the cursor. You could call [SetSystemCursor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648395.aspx) to globally change cursor shapes. I wouldn't recommend it, though. Users won't like this.

Comment: i want a color picker feature for the software, where the user suppose to be able to pick any colour on the screen. Right not the cursor can only change to eye dropper within the popup dialog, which doesnt make sense for the user.

Comment: Safest way to implement this is to create a transparent window, covering the entire screen. That allows you to control the cursor shape, and it's also a safe solution for receiving mouse clicks.